# Image created using GD not proper in size and font - PHP

Tags: php, gd, font-awesome

I have created an image using the style of a div. The below shown is my div.

[image]

I am saving the style of the div in json format including background color, height, width, text, textcolor etc in database. The array looks like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [itmTpe] => website
            [width] => 110px
            [height] => 25px
            [left] => 350px
            [top] => 122px
            [zIndex] => 101
            [dataB_URL] => 
            [text] => Website
            [iconDisp] => inline-block
            [icon] => fa-globe
            [font] => 22px
            [color] => rgb(255, 255, 255)
            [background] => rgb(7, 157, 236)
        )
        ............
)
```

Using these details I am constructing an image. The code I have done is:

```
$json_code    =   json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($result['CP_Item']));  // returns array of div details
$i=1;
header('Content-Type: image/png');
foreach($json_code as $cp_item)   // I have many such div elements with different styles
{
if($cp_item->itmTpe!='show_image' && $cp_item->itmTpe!='show_carousel' && $cp_item->itmTpe!='youtube_video')
    {
        if($cp_item->width)
            $width=  str_replace('px', '', $cp_item->width);

        if($cp_item->height)
            $height=str_replace('px', '', $cp_item->height);

        $image = imagecreate($width, $height);
        $background=$cp_item->background;
        $bgcolor = str_replace(array('rgb(', ')', ' '), '', $background);
        $arr = explode(',', $bgcolor);
        $background = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr[0],$arr[1],$arr[2] );

        $text=$cp_item->text;

        if($cp_item->color)
            $color=$cp_item->color;

        $txtcolor = str_replace(array('rgb(', ')', ' '), '', $color);
        $txtarr = explode(',', $txtcolor);  
        $textcolor=imagecolorallocate($image, $txtarr[0],$txtarr[1],$txtarr[2] );
        $fontfile='fonts/times.ttf';
        if($cp_item->font)
        {
            $size=str_replace('px', '', $cp_item->font);
        }
        else
        {
            $size=10;
        }

        // find the size of the image
        $xi = ImageSX($image);
        $yi = ImageSY($image);

        // find the size of the text
        $box = ImageTTFBBox($size, 0, $fontfile, $text);

        $xr = abs(max($box[2], $box[4]));
        $yr = abs(max($box[5], $box[7]));

        // compute centering
        $x = intval(($xi - $xr) / 2);
        $y = intval(($yi + $yr) / 2);

        //write the text at calculated position
        imagettftext($image, $size, 0, $x+20, $y, $textcolor, $fontfile , $text);
        $font2 = 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf';


        $icontext=$icon[$cp_item->icon];
        //places another text with smaller size
        imagettftext($image,  $size, 0, $x, $y, $textcolor, $font2, $icontext);
        $file="createdimages/$pid/$i.png";
        imagepng($image, $file);
        $i++;
        imagedestroy($image);
   }
}
```

The image is getting created successfully. The problem is that the text in the image appears  bigger than the font size used in div. I am using the font Times New Roman for both div text and image. But both shows differences. The resultant image is :

[image]

Also the size of the image looks smaller than the div size. I am constructing the image with the same width, height and font size of the div. I am not getting what is the problem with this?

I am new to GD. Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Font should have an unit in point not in pixel. Actually, GD outputs an image as expected(110x25), whereas your div may has an inner paddings which increase the image dimensions.